# 503 The service is unavailable Azure Hosting (S1 Service Plan)

Tags: azure

Today I started receiving a 503 error "The service is unavailable." from a web app. The other web apps on the same (S1) service plan seem to be working fine, so I don't think this is a quota issue. The issue started after a simple stop / start of the app service this morning. I've tried searching for solutions but haven't found anything helpful. Can anyone shed some insight on why I may be receiving this error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem comes from maxed out SNAT ports from a separate application within the same service plan.